# How to switch between content controls via c# code, without button pressing?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contentcontrol

I have a c# application (wpf, mvvm). I have 3 radio button that describe 3 vertical tabs, each has a command (ICommand) to show a content control (a view), which is also stated in XAML. The switching between controls in c# code, is done by making one view.Visibility = Visible, and others - hidden. All works well when clicking on the tabs.
But, I now want after a specific timeout of inactivity - to switch to the "Home" content control, but with no luck. The timer is timeout properly, and on timerElapsed, I get to the function that makes this Home content control Visible, and the others Hidden (as I do when I select this tab), but the content control won't change.

```
`<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,85,0,0">
                    <RadioButton Content="{l:Translation HomePage}" 
                                 IsChecked="{Binding IsHomeMode, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=True}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource LeftNavigation_ToggleButtonStyle}" 
                                 Command="{Binding ShowHomePageCommand}"/>

                    <RadioButton Content="{l:Translation PatientList}" 
                                 Style="{StaticResource LeftNavigation_ToggleButtonStyle}" 
                                 Command="{Binding ShowAllCustomersCommand}"/>

                    <RadioButton Content="{l:Translation ResumeSession}"  
                                 Style="{StaticResource LeftNavigation_ToggleButtonStyle}" 
                                 Command="{Binding ShowAllSessionsCommand}"/>
                </StackPanel>`
<Grid>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding SessionsHistoryView}"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding HomepageView}"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Please, give us sample of your code that seems to not work.

Comment: I can't manage to attach code.. not with 4 spaces or '. '

Comment: @KrzysztofMańkowski, I added the relavant XAML code. In the C# code, I just create an ICommand in which I send as a parameter the function that shows each content control (Visibility.Visible, and Vidden foe the other view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding to View means that your ViewModel contains property with it and it's not an MVVM way. There is a better way:

1. Define CurrentPage property in your parent `ViewModel`.

   ```
   private object _currentPage;

   public object CurrentPage
   {
       get { return _currentPage; }
       set
       {
           _currentPage = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentPage));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Bind only one content control to it

   ```
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
   ```
3. Create a `DataTemplate` for each page `ViewModel` in `ResourceDictionary`

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomePageViewModel}">
           <!--View definition goes here-->
       </DataTemplate>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
4. Register your `ResourceDictionary` in your App's dictionary or anywhere you need

   ```
   <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="Views.xaml"/>
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
   ```
5. Set required `ViewModel` to `CurrentPage` property in your command implementations. You can add timeout or any other logic here. Prefer async execution of commands.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey Alonzov, changing the ContentControl binding to one active view, and handling the logic inside ViewModel was the key to the solution.